# Are these integrations stringently done?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I would like to verify that my calculations are clear and correct without unreasonable assumptions. For context it's a course in calculus with focus on analysis. The following are the questions:

a) Calculate: $\int \sin(2x)\ e^x \, dx$

b) Calculate: $\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2} \, dx$

c) An ellips is given by $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$. Use integrals to prove that $A=\pi ab$.

---

Solutions:

**a)**
$\sin(2x)$ and $e^x$ are continuous functions, their combinations and derivatives are too. This allows us to make use of partial integration and let $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ and $g(x)=e^x$. We then have:
\begin{align*}
%
    \int \sin(2x)e^x \, dx
    &= \ e^x\sin(2x)+C_1 - \int 2\cos(2x)e^x\, dx \\
%
    %\int \sin(2x)e^x \, dx
    &= \ e^x\sin(2x)+C_1 - \left(2\cos(2x)e^x+C_2+\int 4\sin(2x)e^x\, dx\right) \\
%
    %\int \sin(2x)e^x \, dx
    &= \ e^x\sin(2x)+C_1 - 2\cos(2x)e^x -C_2 - 4 \int \sin(2x)e^x\, dx \\
%
    5\int \sin(2x)e^x\, dx
    &= e^x(\sin(2x)-2\cos(2x))+C_1-C_2\\
%
 C=C_1-C_2 \Rightarrow
    \int \sin(2x)e^x\, dx
    &= \frac{e^x}{5}(\sin(2x)-2\cos(2x))+C \\
\end{align*}

**b)** Just as before our function and its derivative are continuous. We can then calculate it with the following change of variable. Let $x^2=t \Rightarrow  xdx = dt/2$
\begin{align*}
  \int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2} \, dx =&
  \ \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-t} \, dt =
  -\frac{1}{2}\left[e^{-t}\right]_0^\infty\\
  =& -\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}e^{-t}\right)-1\right) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

**c)** Break out $y$ and integrate:
$$
  y=b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}} \Rightarrow \int_0^a y \, dx =
  \int_0^a b \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}} dx $$

which one can see is the area of one quadrant of the ellips. This integral and its function are continuous. Since $a\neq 0$ and we have real number integration limits we can deduce that it will converge. Let's parameterise as following

$$x=a\cos{t} \Rightarrow dx=-a\sin{t}\,dt \qquad $$

$t$ must go from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for one quadrant, so we can multiply the integral by $4$ to get the entire area of the ellips because of its symmetric quadrants:

$$A=4b \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1-\cos^2{t}}(-a\sin{t})dt
  =-4ab \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2{t}\,dt$$

With trigonometry we can write $\sin^2{t}$ as $\dfrac{\cos(2t)-1}{2}$

$$A=-2ab \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(2t)-1 \, dt =
    -2ab \left[\frac{\sin(2t)}{2}-1\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\\
  A= 2ab\left(0+\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \pi ab$$

Comment: Your answers are correct (a & b) and the calculations (a, b & c) look fine; well done.